# Is there a way to run a validation of the configuration on a .sln file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that builds in various configurations via MSBuild on the build server.  Unfortunately developers are regularly forgetting to add the correct custom configurations to their projects.  Is there a way to validate the solution file / project files as part of the check-in to TFS?

Comment: This is *exactly* what a build server is supposed to do.  Break the build when somebody screws up the check-in.  Kitchen cleaning duty or wearing a dunce hat for the day makes them more cautious.  And the break needs to be highly visible, email to everybody.  Including the boss.

Comment: I was hoping that we could do a validation prior to breaking the build...

Comment: This is what gated checkins are for in TFS 2010. I still prefer the dunce hat, though. Helps developers learn not to break the build.

Comment: Actually there is a second reason I am hoping for a validation step.  The build doesn't always fail because of missing configurations - sometimes it presents as a run time issue during testing and other times it is as simple as not matching the expected path for unit test project binaries and they don't get added to the unit test run.